# JavaFX Application in Eclipse doesn't open in floating mode correctly in i3wm

Tags: javafx, i3

If I start my Main-Methode in my main-class in Eclipse, the program start correctly in tiling mode (i3wm). Now i try to move it to floating mode with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>mod4</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>, it goes to floating mode. But the window has only 5x5 pixels and don't open with the given size (500x300) in the code. Do I miss something for JavaFX in floating mode?

```
System:
Arch-Linux 4.17.2-1-Arch
JDK: aur-package called: JDK
Eclipse-Version: the latest from the repositories (eclipse-java version: 4.7.3.a-1)
```

I used the JDK from the AUR, because JavaFX doesn't worked for me, with the preinstalled JDK-version from eclipse-java (jre10-openjdk/jdk10-openjdk).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this while trying to get my program to launch in floating mode. For me, it works correctly. Could you post your main fxml document? I have something like prefHeight="901.0" prefWidth="1360.0" in the root compoenent.